# Document that property of interface is a class and not instance of class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have some legacy AngularJs code which I am trying to document for a new project of ours using Typescript, but I have run into a bit of an odd case and I am facing a problem.

Essentially we have a Service/Instance of a "class" which has some properties, these properties are actually classes. A Basic example would maybe look like this:

```js
function MySingletonService() {
  function SomeClass(...) {
    ...
  }
  SomeClass.parse= function() {
    ...
    return new SomeClass(...);
  };
  this.SomeClass = SomeClass;
}
angular.module(...).service('MySingletonService', MySingletonService);
// Inside a RUN call here, for demonstrative purposes in this issue, it would be used as:
// The actual use in the legacy project happens in other services, directives, components etc.
angular.run(['MySingletonService', function(service) {
  var instance1OfClass = new service.SomeClass();
  var instance2OfClass = new service.SomeClass();
  var instance3OfClass = service.SomeClass.parse(...);
}]);
```

But I am a bit at a loss on how to document the "MySingletonService" in a typescript .d.ts file.
Normally I would just declare classes and interface for the service, like so:

```js
export declare class SomeClass {
  constructor(...);
  static parse(...):SomeClass;
}

export declare interface IMySingletonService {
  SomeClass: ???;
}
```

If I define it as `SomeClass: SomeClass`, then obviously we see it as an Instance of that class, but here it's the actual class that is assigned to the Property. As such, I have not been able to find an example that looks like what I have.

Searching for just that has proven a bit hard as it basically ends up with examples of how to define the property as an instance if the class, which is straight forward.

---

It looks like I can get fairly close if I accept having to "Double Document" my code like so:

```js
export declare class SomeClass {
  constructor(...);
  static parse(...):SomeClass;
}

export declare interface IMySingletonService {
  SomeClass: {
    new (...): SomeClass;
    parse(...): SomeClass;
  };
}
```

But isn't there a better way?

Comment: You want `typeof SomeClass`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks, could you provide that as an answer with a tiny example so I can mark that as the accepted answer? (As it indeed works)

Comment: I figured I'd mark it as a duplicate but I can't find a "canonical" question about this so sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `typeof SomeClass`

The type `SomeClass` describes an *instance* of `SomeClass`.  In order to describe *the class itself* you should use `typeof SomeClass`.

This type includes the constructor and all static methods.  So you can call `new service.SomeClass()` and also `service.SomeClass.parse()`.

```
declare class SomeClass {
    constructor();
    static parse(): SomeClass;
}

export declare interface IMySingletonService {
    SomeClass: typeof SomeClass;
}

declare const service: IMySingletonService;

const obj = new service.SomeClass(); // obj has type SomeClass

const parsed = service.SomeClass.parse(); // parsed has type: SomeClass
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ND5zzm)

Per [the docs (previous version)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#classes):

> Next, we then use the class directly. Here we create a new variable called `greeterMaker`. This variable will hold the class itself, or said another way its constructor function. Here we use `typeof Greeter`, that is “give me the type of the `Greeter` class itself” rather than the instance type. Or, more precisely, “give me the type of the symbol called `Greeter`,” which is the type of the constructor function. This type will contain all of the static members of `Greeter` along with the constructor that creates instances of the `Greeter` class. We show this by using `new` on `greeterMaker`, creating new instances of `Greeter` and invoking them as before.